# Watching for change in filtered items in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a simple Angular app which has some data, and an input box to filter that data.

```
<input class="form-control" ng-model="filters.generic" />

<h3>{{filteredUsers.length}} filtered users</h3>
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="user in filteredUsers = (data.userData | filter:filters.generic )">
     {{user.registration.firstName}}
  </li>                                    
</ul>
```

The 'filteredUsers' variable stores the users with the applied filter. That all works absolutely fine. However, I'd like to be able to add a watch to execute a particular function whenever this 'filteredUsers' variable changes (whenever the user types anything in the input box).

I do *not* want to simply add a method to ng-change on the input, because I want to introduce other filters elsewhere.

I thought that I could do this in my controller with

```
$scope.$watch('filteredUsers', function () {        
    alert('something');
});
```

This executes once, when the application loads, and then never again. What must I do to make this watch for changes to filteredUsers?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use $watchCollection() instead of $watch()

Keep in mind that the filter on an ng-repeat could be running way more frequently than you need or expect it to, and adversely affect the performance of your code.
Even though you said you don't want to use ng-change, I think you should reconsider that and only update your array when needed.

```
<input class="form-control" ng-model="filters.generic" ng-change="genericFilterChange()" />
```

---

```
var updateFilteredUsers = function(){
  $scope.filteredUsers = $filter('filter')($scope.data.userData, $scope.filters.generic);
  alert('something');
};

var genericFilterChange = function(){
  updateFilteredUsers();
  updateOtherFilteredThings();
};
```